# How to modify get_queryset result value

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to modify my get_queryset result

Here is my my filter, view and serializer

**view.py**

```
 class AccountDetailFilter(filters.FilterSet):
        product_key = filters.CharFilter(name='product__product_name')
        account_name = filters.AllValuesFilter(name='account__account_key')
        service_provider_name = filters.CharFilter(name='product__service_provider__service_provider_name', )
        allocation_key = filters.CharFilter(name='account__account_allocation__allocation_key')

        class Meta:
            model = BillingLine
            fields = ('product_key', 'account_name', 'service_provider_name', 'allocation_key')

class AccountDetailList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BillingSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = AccountDetailFilter


    def get_queryset(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        start_date = self.kwargs.get('start_date_time', now)
        end_date = self.kwargs.get('end_date_time', now)
        serializer = BillingSerializer(data={'start_date': start_date, 'end_date': end_date})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        queryset = BillingLine.objects.select_related().filter(start_date__gte=start_date, end_date__lte=end_date)
        queryset =  queryset.order_by('-id')
        print(queryset.count())
        return queryset
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class BillingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    start_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    end_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    account_key = serializers.CharField(source='account_id',required=False)
    product_key = serializers.CharField(source='product_id',required=False)
    total_amount = serializers.FloatField(required=False)
```

After retrieving the result(ie get_queryset), I need to modify/add the data in the result . Is there any way to do this .

Also can we get the other field values to serializers from the result queryset. Because the  `queryset = BillingLine.objects.select_related().filter(start_date__gte=start_date, end_date__lte=end_date)` is returning the almost all the data (sepecifally product name which is from products table)

Comment: Add all keys into serializer  which are returning from views queryset

Comment: @AnupYadav I have added the fields in the serializer which the query is returning . But it is not working . Only the fields in the main table is returning in the resultset

Comment: Yes, you need to define `field_name = serializers.IntegerField()` and `field_name = serializers.CharField()` at class level not at META class. And need to add those fields into `fields` or `extra_fields = ('field_name','so on...')`

Comment: @AnupYadav I have added that

Comment: `fields` or `extra_fields = ('field_name','so on...')` ? This section is missing at your question

Comment: sure I will try that. Is there any way to edit the data after retrieving , say I wanted to sum up all the amount, is that possible

Comment: Yes, definitely you can add and insert into list of result in get_queryset itself. as it is is key value, you can do anything with that list, but make sure all those keys are presents at serializers

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `get_queryset()` method would serve your purpose perfectly.

For Example:
in your `views.py` :

```
class AccountDetailList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BillingSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = AccountDetailFilter
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = YourModel.objects.filter(**filter_parameter)
        return qs

    def list(self):
        try:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
            serialize_value = YourSerializers(queryset,many=True,context={'request': self.request}).data
            #Here in "serialize_value" you can append your data as much as you wish
            return_val = {
                'modified_serialize_value': serialize_value
            }    
            return Response(return_val, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type='application/json')
        except Exception as E:
            return Response({'error': str(E)}, status=status.HTTP_408_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, content_type='application/json')
```

I hope this will help.